# Looking for open source based Multi tenant LMS (Learning management system) other than moodle

Tags: php, open-source, moodle

We're looking for a LMS that we can use as the basis for a new product we're rolling out.

As it's principally a content based thing, we need to base everything on a LMS, but there's a few things we need:

As we're supporting tens - hundreds of users, we ideally need a multi-tenant LMS (single shared code base), that can support different designs per site
As we're selling in functionality, we need something that will let us deploy a new 'module' and switch it on/off on a per site basis
We prefer stuff that is open source (PHP)
Before I consider building something, is there anything out there that's any good?

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few opensource LMS alternatives:
http://www.dotlrn.org/
http://www.efrontlearning.net/
http://www.dokeos.com/
http://www.sakaiproject.org/
http://atutor.ca/

You can also look at SCORM Cloud that takes away a lot of headaches for deploying content. All you need is a frontend like Wordpress or Joomla.

Answer (score 2):

As a free open source lms I would suggest Moodle - http://www.moodle.org.
Among commercial e-learning solutions I tried, I'd choose JoomlaLMS - http://www.joomlalms.com - it also has an open sourced version and is easy to set up.